# Use jquery to generate a dynamic href and then read the class of the <a>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to use jquery to read the "class" of an  and then use the result to hide/show divs.  The href= is dynamically generated in php in the format href="#pop-up(number)", where the number is between 1 and approximately 60.

I have used the code

```
var value = $('a[href="#pop-up49"]').attr('class');
alert(value);
```

and I get the desired result, but when I try to substitute the #pop-49 with a built expression as follows

```
for ( var i = 49, limit=60; i < limit; i++ ){
var value = $('a[href="\"" + "#pop-up" + i + "\""]').attr('class');
alert(value);
}
```

I get the result "undefined".

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong as reading this expression directly seems to give what I would expect, i.e "#pop-up49"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate your value properly here:

```
var value = $('a[href="#pop-up' + i + '"]').attr('class');
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick response.  I knew what the problem was just couldn't see how to resolve it.  Guess I need to learn more about concatenating